invalid hook call in react going from one component to an other
I have a component card.js
import React from "react";
import Imagehelper from "./helper/Imagehelper";
import ProductCompare from "./ProductCompare";

const isAuthenticated = true;

const Card = ({ product, addtoCart = true, removefromCart = true }) => {
  const productTitle = product ? product.subbranch3 : "نام محصول";
  const productdescription = product ? product.goodproperties : "توضیحات محصول";
  const productPrice = product ? product.price : "قیمت محصول";

  const addToCart = () => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      console.log("محصول به سبد خرید اضافه شد");
    } else {
      console.log("لطفا وارد حساب کاربری خود شوید");
    }
  };

  const showAddToCart = (addtoCart) => {
    return (
      addtoCart && (
        <button
          onClick={addToCart}
          className="btn btn-outline-success mt-2 mb-2"
        >
          افزودن به سبد خرید
        </button>
      )
    );
  };

  const showRemoveFromCart = (removefromCart) => {
    return (
      removefromCart && (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("محصول از سبد خرید حذف شد");
          }}
          className="btn btn-outline-danger mt-2 mb-2"
        >
          حذف از سبد خرید
        </button>
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="card text-white bg-dark border border-info" dir="rtl">
      <div className="card-header lead">{productTitle}</div>
      <div className="card-body">
        <Imagehelper product={product} />
        <p className="lead bg-success font-weight-normal text-wrap">
          {productdescription}
        </p>
        <p className="btn btn-block btn-success rounded btn-sm px-4">
          {productPrice}تومان
        </p>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">{showAddToCart(addtoCart)}</div>
          <div className="col-12">{showRemoveFromCart(removefromCart)}</div>
          <div className="col-12">
            <button
              className="btn btn-block btn-outline-info mt-2 mb-2"
              onClick={() => ProductCompare(product)}
            >
              compare product
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;

in that i make a button that when you click it it will call another component ProcuctCompare and in ProductCompare i want to compare products with each other
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getProductsAttribute } from "./helper/Coreapicalls";
import Imagehelper from "./helper/Imagehelper";

const ProductCompare = (product) => {
  console.log("product is:", product);
  const [allproductsAttribute, setAllProductsAttribute] = useState([]);
  const [singleProductAttributes, setSingleProductAttributes] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  let productID = product["id"];

  const loadAllProductAttribute = () => {
    getProductsAttribute().then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setError(data.error);
        console.log(data.error);
      } else {
        setAllProductsAttribute(data);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadAllProductAttribute();
  }, [product]);

  console.log("product attributes are:", allproductsAttribute);
  console.log(error);

  const loadSingleProductAttributes = () => {
    setSingleProductAttributes(
      allproductsAttribute.filter((pa) => pa["good"] === productID),
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadSingleProductAttributes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="row" dir="rtl">
      <div className="col-3 mb-3">
        <div className="row">
          <Imagehelper product={product} />
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {singleProductAttributes.map((value, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index} className="col-4 mb-4">
                <p className="text-white">{value}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCompare;

The problem is when i clicked compare product in card.js it throws an error "Invalid hook call" i think i obeyed all react hooks roles but i can not understand why react shows me that error
looked react hooks call roles and think i obeyed them

onClick={ () => ProductCompare(product) }

This is not a valid way to render a component. You must set state to cause a rerender, and then during that render return a <ProductCompare/> element. For example:
const [selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState(null);
// ...
return (
  <>
    {selectedProduct && <ProductCompare product={selectedProduct} />}
    <div className='card text-white bg-dark border border-info' dir='rtl'>
    // ...
    <button 
      className='btn btn-block btn-outline-info mt-2 mb-2' 
      onClick={() => setSelectedProduct(product)}
    >
      compare product
    </button>
    // ...
    </div>
  </>
)

ProductCompare also needs a small change to expect the product as an individual prop:
const ProductCompare = ({ product }) => {

(added { and } to destructure the props)
